# rowfilter error with sql where

Tags: c#, sql

In C# I have set my datatable's `rowfilter` to

```
string dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
string rowFitler = "DisplayStartDate <= '" + dateNow + "' and (case DisplayEndDate when '' then 1 else 0 END  = 1 or  DisplayEndDate >= '" + dateNow + "') and formactive = 1";
```

Sample values in

```
DisplayStartDate <= '4/18/2014' and (case [DisplayEndDate] when '' then 1 else 0 END  = 1 or  DisplayEndDate >= '4/18/2014') and formactive = 1
```

I am getting an error:

> Missing operand after '[DisplayEndDate]' operator.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: see if date is between start and end, if enddate is '' (default) then pass logic works fine in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DisplayStartDate <= '4/18/2014' and (cast(DisplayEndDate as varchar) = '' or  DisplayEndDate >= '4/18/2014') and formactive = 1
```

Comment: close needed System.String because its .net